# What is the role of "in the first inning" lexically?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, parts-of-speech, functions

**In the first inning** he pitched with great control.

In the first inning, I think describe the whole sentence, but It might modify the verb pitched, What function the phrase has in the sentence??

Comment: The PP "in the first inning" is a preposed adjunct, i.e. a **modifier** in clause structure.

Comment: And ***After the game**, we had a beer*.  The phrase situates the main clause, temporally.

Comment: This is a very pronounced US/UK usage split I wasn't aware of until now! OP's cited (singular?) [***In the first inning***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=In+the+first+inning%2CIn+the+first+innings&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) is almost exclusively AmE, where in BrE it's always (plural?) [***In the first innings.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=In+the+first+inning%2CIn+the+first+innings&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject is "he". The verb is "pitched". "In the first inning" modifies "pitched", saying when he pitched.

Comment: In other words, "in the first inning" is a preposed adjunct in clause structure. I'd say that it modifies the whole VP "pitched with great control".